# How can I scrape this data?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to scrape the statistics from this page:

```
url <- "http://www.pgatour.com/players/player.20098.stuart-appleby.html/statistics"
```

Specifically, I want to grab the data in the table that's underneath Stuart's headshot. It's headlined by "Stuart Appleby - 2015 STATS PGA TOUR"

I attempt to use `rvest`, in combo with the Selector Gadget (http://selectorgadget.com/).

```
url_html <- url %>% html()
url_html %>% 
        html_nodes(xpath = '//*[(@id = "playerStats")]//td')
```

'Should' get me the table without, for example, the row on top that says "Recap  -- Rank -- Additional Stats"

```
url_html <- url %>% html()
url_html %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[(@id = "playerStats")] | //th//*[(@id = "playerStats")]//td')
```

'Should' get me the table with that "Recap -- Rank -- Add'l Stats" line.

Neither do.

Obvs I'm a complete newb when it comes to web scraping. When I click on 'view source' for that webpage, the data contained in the table isn't there.

In the source code, where I *think* the table should be starting, is this bit of code:

```
<script id="playerStatsTourTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{each(t, tour) tours}}
        {{if pgatour.players.shouldProcessTour(tour.tourCodeLC)}}
        <div class="statistics-head">
            <h2 class="title">Stuart&nbsp;Appleby - <b>${year} STATS 
.
.
.
```

So, it appears the table is stored somewhere (Json? Jquery? Javascript? Are those terms applicable here?) that isn't accessible to the `html()` function. Is there anyway to use `rvest` to grab this data? Is there an `rvest` equivalent for grabbing data that is stored in this manner?

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone who helps you is in violation of their ToC's - `You shall not use or permit or facilitate others to use PGATOUR.com by automated electronic processes, robots, spiders, scrapers, webcrawlers, or other computer programs that monitor, copy or download data or other content found on or accessed through PGATOUR.com, including without limitation real time scoring, video, audio, statistics, polling, or data content, whether current or archival.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use the GET request that the page is making to get the raw data from their API and work on parsing that...

`content(a)` gives you a list representation... basically the output from `fromJSON()`
or
`as(a, "character")` gives you the raw JSON

```
library("httr")
a <- GET("http://www.pgatour.com/data/players/20098/2014stat.json")
content(a)
as(a, "character")
```

Comment: Thanks! Question: How did you discover the url `http://www.pgatour.com/data/players/20098/2014stat.json` ?

Comment: In chrome... right click, inspect element. Then click the network tab. Then change years using the dropdown on the webpage and watch the network tab for new entries.

Comment: Thanks! I actually haven't been able to click the dropdown box for year after I do the right click > inspect > network. I can click the dropdown for player, but not for year. Also, when I do the dropdown for player, it appears there are tons of new entries in the network tab. Do you have a method of sifting through these to pick out the important ones?

Comment: The ones that are GET or POST entries are the ones that you should key in on. You have to check out the headers sometimes and copy those over for a POST, but GETs are usually easy, like above...

Answer (score 1):

Check this out.

Open source project on GitHub scraping PGA data: https://github.com/zachwill/golf/blob/master/pga.py